# How to evaluate $45^\frac {1-a-b}{2-2a}$ where $90^a=2$ and $90^b=5$ without using logarithm?

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

Let $90^a=2$ and $90^b=5$, Evaluate

## $45^\frac {1-a-b}{2-2a}$

I know that the answer is 3 when I used logarithm, but I need to show to a student how to evaluate this without involving logarithm. Also, no calculators.

Comment: I think something along the lines of $10^{-1} = 90^{-a-b} \implies 3^2 = 90^{1-a-b} \implies 3 = 90^{\frac{1-a-b}{2}}$. I'll put further information as I move along.

Comment: Maybe along the lines of letting $\sqrt[a]{2}=90; \, \sqrt[b]{5}=90$ and knowing that $45 \times 2 = 90$ plus also use @hjpotter92 's comment.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thank you for your help. I have a question though. Can you show me how $3^2$ is $90^{1-a-b}$?

Comment: @Aldon thanks for your input :)

Comment: @DioPauloHonorario Multiplying both sides by $90$ in $10^{-1} = 90^{-a-b}$

Comment: @hjpotter92 thanks dude! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try.

$$10 = 90^{a+b} \Rightarrow 3^2 = 90^{1-a-b} \Rightarrow 3 = 90^{\frac{1-a-b}{2}}.$$

Then, $$45 = 90^{(1-a-b)+b} = 90^{1-a}.$$

So, $$45^{\frac{1}{1-a}} = 90 \Rightarrow 45^{\frac{1-a-b}{2(1-a)}} = 90^{\frac{1-a-b}{2}} = 3.$$

Comment: I had just arrived at the result $45=90^{1-a}$. =)

Comment: But your comments are very helpful for OP :)

Comment: @GAVD Thank you so much for making my life simpler! :))

Answer (score 0):

$$2=90^a=(2\cdot5\cdot3^2)^a\iff5^a3^{2a}=2^{1-a}$$

and similarly, $$5=90^b\iff5^{1-b}3^{-2b}=2^b$$

Equating the powers of $2,$
$$\implies(5^a3^{2a})^b=(5^{1-b}3^{-2b})^{1-a}\iff3^{2b}=5^{1-a-b}$$

$$45^{1-a-b}=(3^2\cdot5)^{1-a-b}=3^{2-2(a+b)}\cdot5^{1-a-b}=3^{2-2(a+b)}\cdot3^{2b}$$
$$\implies45^{1-a-b}=3^{2(1-a)}$$

$\implies$ one of the values of $$45^{\frac{1-a-b}{2(1-a)}}$$ is $3$

Answer (score -1):

Given $90^a = 2$, $90^b = 5$

$$(90/2)^{(1-a-b)/(2–2a)}$$
$$=(90/90^a)^{(1-a-b)/(2–2a)}$$
$$=(90^{1-a})^{(1-a-b)/(2(1–a))}$$
$$=90^{(1-a-b)/2}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{90}{90^a 90^b}}$$
$$=\sqrt{\frac{90}{2\cdot 5}} = \sqrt{9} =3$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).